# What type of ANOVA design to conduct?

Tags: manova, anova

The scenario is as follows: I want to compare engagement of users when they are exposed to two types of product (black and white imagery and colorful imagery).  Engagement consists of 4 different components: Novelty, Attention, Endurability, Felt Environment.  I have collected data for: Novelty (B/W and Color), Attention (B/W and Color), Endurability (B/W and Color), Felt Environment (B/W and Color).  It is a within-subjects ANOVA design, with independent variables "product types" x novelty, attention, endurably, felt environment.  I want to compare engagement when users are exposed to B/W and Colorful stimuli, by comparing the four different components of engagement individually. How should I approach this problem? Can I consider engagement to have 4 levels? I think it is a 4x2 ANOVA repeated measures design.

Comment: what are your key hypotheses ? and indicate sample data  with you ?